# Xml answer : root name is not known

Tags: android, simple-framework

I am doing a request.
I can receive one of the following answers :

```
  <MyCustomObject>
     <data>
       <name>...</name>
       <property>...</property>
     </data>
  </MyCustomObject>
```

or

```
<CustomError>
  <data>
    <errorMessage>....</errorMessage>
    <code>...</code>
  </data>
</CustomError>
```

I am using SimpleXml and retrofit . And I create class

MyCustomAnswerResponse. Generraly in declaration I add annotation for @Root but in this case root can be CustomError or MyCustomObject . How can I solve this ?

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: If your response in form of SoapObject,Then you can use object.hasProperty("PropertyName").Surely this can be solvable do some research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the root name is unknown , or there are multiple values in object you can use @Default annotation.

```
@Default 
MyCustomAnswerResponse{

 @Element 
   ....

 @Element 
 .....
 }
```